# how to show custom layout in my main layout?

Tags: android

im using custom listview in my main layout from here  https://github.com/NikolaDespotoski/DoubleTapListViewHandler/tree/master/src/com/nikola/despotoski/doubletaplistview  but problem is this wil create custom programicaly layout but in my code i already set content setContentView(R.layout.bid); so how do i add new custom layout in my  main layout?? help me what will i do??

```
 private CustomListView bidlist = null;


public class BidSchema extends BackBaseActivity  implements OnItemDoubleTapLister {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.bid);

          bidlist = new CustomListView(this);
          bidlist.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
          setContentView(bidlist);
          back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bidback);
          bottomlayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottom_layout);
          scroll_down = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.down);
          scroll_up = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.up);
```

**Layout XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bar1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentdesc" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bidback"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_arr"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentdesc" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconpic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/treasure"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentdesc" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bar"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentdesc"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Bid"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/jobhead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="22sp"


            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Plot"

            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobpick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:text="Job"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
         </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/bidlist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/jobhead"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fields_bg"
        android:visibility="visible" >
       </ListView>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        layout="@layout/bottom" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout xml.

Comment: check it i post alrready

Comment: In your code you doing set contentView two times, possible road block for your problem. First time setContentView(R.layout.bid); and second time with setContentView(bidlist);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an `id` to your parent `RelativeLayout` as below to add new view to this layout later...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg2"
    android:id="@+id/layout" >

    ..........

</RelativeLayout >
```

Now, add your `bidlist` to the parent layout as below...

```
RelativeLayout rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

bidlist = new CustomListView(this);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

rootLayout.addView(bidlist, lp);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have implement custom Listview then you should change this.

```
      setContentView(R.layout.bid);

      bidlist = new CustomListView(this);
      bidlist.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
      setContentView(bidlist);
```

to

```
      bidlist = new CustomListView(this);
      bidlist.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
      setContentView(bidlist);
```

***UPDATE:***

```
RelativeLayout rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

bidlist = new CustomListView(this);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

rootLayout.addView(bidlist, rlp);
```

Because you can't call setContentView() two times. So you have to add it in your parent Relative Layout. so check that.

Comment: @user3388003 chk my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't setContentView.
If main activity show posted xml, just make Adapter implements baseAdapter, and then just listview.setAdapter( you make adapter)

Comment: Adapter implements baseAdapter what its mean?

Comment: im extend  OnItemDoubleTapLister  from this class https://github.com/NikolaDespotoski/DoubleTapListViewHandler/blob/master/src/com/nikola/despotoski/doubletaplistview/CustomListView.java so how i will show listview in my mainlayout tell me